# Spring MVC Controller can't connect directly with Spring Web Flow?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I recently had to move the first step of a web flow out of the direct web flow logic where it had been, and placed it in a separate controller.   So the step that used to be this:

```
File jsp/stuff/flow.xml:

<view-state id="startFlow" model="flowModel" view="flow/start" ></view-state>
```

Is now supposed to be reached like this:

```
Controller Startup.java:

@RequestMapping("mything.html")
public String startFlow(Model model) {
    return "jsp/stuff";
}
```

The flow starts just fine when going to  (localhost)/MyApp/jsp/stuff.   It's just when the controller sends you there you get this ugly error:

```
   javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'jsp/stuff' in servlet with name 'MyApp'
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1190)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Can anybody explain this?

Comment: You need to do a `redirect` or `forward` to start the flow.

Comment: Thanks!   That turned out to be the answer.

Comment: Posted my comment as answer so you can accept if it solved your problem. Thank you.

Comment: Done!  Thank you for doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a `redirect:` or `forward:` to start the flow.